# Find how many units are available each day of date range

Tags: mysql, sql

I am making a table schema for a booking system. Booking can be done for days or hours.

For example : 100 laptops Are available, 20 people rented 35 laptops in different date periods. With different checkin and checkout times.

I want to generate a booking calendar from the result that shows how many units are available each day.

I am trying to generate a result that shows unit count for a date range such as 2016-01-01 10:30 to 2016-01-04 10:30.

```
Date       | availableUnits
2016-01-01 | 10
2016-01-02 | 6
2016-01-03 | 0
2016-01-04 | 11
```

Table of ad

```
id  | title             | unit
142 | HP Laptop         | 100
143 | Apple MacBook Air | 25
```

Table of booking

```
id  | ad_id | start_date            | end_date              | units
5   | 143   | 2015-08-17 18:18:00   | 2015-08-24 18:18:00   | 5
8   | 142   | 2015-08-20 05:30:00   | 2015-08-31 05:30:00   | 2
1   | 143   | 2015-08-20 16:59:00   | 2015-08-25 16:58:00   | 1
6   | 142   | 2015-08-25 20:37:00   | 2015-08-29 20:37:00   | 1
10  | 142   | 2015-08-27 05:30:00   | 2015-08-29 04:30:00   | 1
11  | 143   | 2015-09-01 05:30:00   | 2015-09-05 05:30:00   | 3
4   | 142   | 2015-09-01 17:20:00   | 2015-10-12 17:20:00   | 2
3   | 143   | 2015-09-01 21:28:00   | 2015-09-30 21:28:00   | 5
19  | 143   | 2015-09-03 05:30:00   | 2015-09-26 05:30:00   | 1
12  | 142   | 2015-09-05 05:30:00   | 2015-09-10 05:30:00   | 1
```

I have created a SQL fiddle if anyone like to run queries.
[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20f395)

I have tried few different approaches without much success. Storing availability for each day is an option. But that can be a big issue when number of ads go up. Even small number of ads can generate large sets of data if i do that.

Any suggestion is welocme

Comment: What time of each day are you using as the sampling point to get the number of available units? You said *such as 2016-01-01 10:30 to 2016-01-04 10:30* so it depends on the user input and something like *2016-01-01 10:30 to 2016-01-04 12:30* would be invalid?

Comment: @FrederickZhang yes that would be valid. Users can choose any date range.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use each record as if there where 2 records.

At the start date of a booking, this has a negative impact on your stock

```
SELECT b1.start_date at_date, -b1.units unitsDiff
FROM ad_bookings b1
```

At the end date of a booking, your stock again increases

```
SELECT b2.end_date at_date, b2.units unitsDiff
FROM ad_bookings b2
```

If you want to know how many units are available at a specific time, you can combine those two queries and sum them up in sorted order:

```
-- availability at specific moment
SELECT grouped.at_date, 
  @sum := COALESCE(@sum,(SELECT unit FROM ads WHERE id = 142)) + grouped.unitsDiff CurrentTotal, grouped.unitsDiff
FROM (
  SELECT sub.at_date, sum(sub.unitsDiff) unitsDiff
  FROM (
      SELECT b1.start_date at_date, -b1.units unitsDiff
      FROM ad_bookings b1
      WHERE b1.ad_id = 142
         UNION
      SELECT b2.end_date at_date, b2.units unitsDiff
      FROM ad_bookings b2
      WHERE b2.ad_id = 142
  ) sub
  GROUP BY sub.at_date
) grouped
ORDER BY grouped.at_date
```

- If you want to do this for a specific range, you only need those `ad_bookings` that overlap in any way with that range.
- If you want to eliminate time, and have specific dates, you can cast your start and end dates. `CAST(b1.start_date AS DATE) at_date`. (You may want to ceil your end_date and floor your start_date)
- If it is explicitely required to have all dates in the range, you can add dummy records like `UNION '2015-10-22' at_date, 0 unitsDiff`
- I would suggest that you query the required ad_bookings (maybe grouped) and let the application logic handle it. But that's up to you.